# Elasticsearch jdbc river plugin with bettermap

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am currently using the the jdbc river plugin to populate data into elasticsearch, and in my relational database there are two columns with double number attribute called `latitude` and `longitude`. I have combined these two as a `geoip.location` attribute so that I can use in `bettermap`. The geoip.location is a string showing like `"lon,lat"`, for example `"95.23,13.54"`.

However, when I add the bettermap panel with this attribute, the map is not loading at all. The strange thing is that if I put geo.locaotin in both `"field"` and `tooltip`, the bettermap start to show, but the location is wrong. It looks like it is considering the geo point as lat,lat instead of lat,lon.

Comment: Can you share your mapping? I think you should not combine lat long it might be possible its passing as string in bettermap. that's why its not showing map. try to extract lat long from `geoip.location` typecast it to double.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to explicitly map your field to be of type geo_point. Than there are multiple formats that you can provided your data in. More information about the mapping is here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html#mapping-geo-point-type

Beware when providing the point as a string, you have to provide it as: lat,lon.

I would first check my mapping, than insert a document myself and finally check again with the river.